# Visual Studio 2008 Syntax Coloring Problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting

In a VB.NET Web Site, the User Types syntax coloring doesn't work.  What are potential causes of this?

Note:  C# works as expected.

Update:  It seems to not understand the difference between a "User Type" and an "Identifier."

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your problem, but you can check it at least. Go to Tools >> Options..., pick Text Editor >> VB.NET and verify that the colors and such are how you like them.

Comment: I had a time where all my text was one color. The solution was to restart VS 2008. Other than that, I'm stumped.

Comment: Has that specific syntax colouring ever worked for VB.NET?  Is it supposed to work?

I have noticed the same problem but pretty much gave up on it because I decided it was that important to worry about at the time.